# SQL query to remove duplicates from a table with 139 columns and load all columns to another table

Tags: sql, db2

I need to remove the duplicates from a table with 139 columns based on 2 columns and load the unique rows with 139 columns into another table.

eg :

```
col1   col2  col3 .....col139
  a      b     .............
  b      c     .............
  a      b     .............
```

o/p:

```
col1   col2  col3 .....col139
 a      b     .............
 b      c     .............
```

need a SQL query for DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "other table" does not exist yet you can create it like this

```
CREATE TABLE othertable LIKE originaltable
```

And the insert the requested row with this statement:

```
INSERT INTO othertable 
    SELECT col1,...,coln
    FROM (SELECT 
              t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1) AS num
          FROM t) t
    WHERE num = 1
```

There are numerous tools out there that generate queries and column lists - so if you do not want to write it by hand you could generate it with these tools or use another SQL statement to select it from the Db2 catalog table (syscat.columns).

Answer (score 1):

You might be better just deleting the duplicates in place. This can be done without specifying a column list.

```
DELETE FROM 
(   SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) AS DUP
    FROM t
) 
WHERE
   DUP > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a) as seqnum
      from t
      ) t;
```

If you don't want `seqnum` in the result set, though, you need to list out all the columns.

Comment: True, I am looking for a way to not have to list all columns and not include seqnum in the result.

Comment: Does you table have a primary key?

Comment: @SnehaS It's easy to construct a list of all table columns separated by comma using LISTAGG function and SYSCAT.COLUMNS system catalog view. Is there another reason preventing you from specifying all table columns in your query?

Answer (score -1):

To find duplicate values in `col1` or any column, you can run the following query:

```
SELECT col1 FROM your_table GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

And if you want to delete those duplicate rows using the value of `col1`, you can run the following query:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM your_table GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

You can use the same approach to delete duplicate rows from the table using `col2` values.